# What type of construction is used in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, absolute-construction

> They hailed Brissenden and his demijohns with acclamation, and, **on
>   being introduced**, Martin learned they were Andy and Parry.

I wonder what type of construction is **on being introduced**.

Is it the absolute construction? If yes, of what type?

Comment: Since the preposition **on** is at its head, I wouldn't consider it to be 'absolute'. I understand it as an adjunct to "Martin learned". It can be repositioned. Compare *They went to the side door **upon being told the front door was locked**.*

Answer (score 4):

**On being introduced** is a participle that leads the reader in to the main clause. These are used all the time in English to set the scene:

> Opening the door, she saw.....
>
> Turning the corner, they found....

It frequently happens that the writer/speaker loses sight of the subject of the main clause (a dangling particple) with results like these:

> After robbing the shop, the policeman chased the thief.

There are numerous examples and explanations at sites like:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/dangling-participles

http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_30.htm

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dangling-participle